# How to overlay image on extruded SVG?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, extrude, svg

So I just got into blender because I need a 3D object to animate in AE. I am having trouble adding a texture to my object. I don't know the terminology all that well, but I tried making a mesh and that didn't seem to work well. Also tried unwrapping, but it didn't work also. The model on the right is a extruded and beveled SVG.

What I'd like to do (as shown in the image below) is to put the image files (on the left) on either sides of the model (on the right). Is there a simpler way I can go about this? Like the image and 3D model are the same exact shape so why couldn't I just paste the images on either side?

Been researching for hours with no return so any feedback helps!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: With an extruded curve you can put an image on the front but I'm not sure you will be able to put one different image on each side, so I guess you need to convert to mesh, unwrap, give your object a material with an Image Texture plugged into the Diffuse node, merge your 2 text images into one to make it simpler, load this image into the Image Texture node, and in the UV Editor move each face of your mesh UV so that it aligns correctly on the text.

Comment: This looks simple enough that you could probably just do the whole thing in AE, unless the animation involves deforming the object.

Answer (score 2):

Easy approach is to use texture mask inside material.

Here I'm using local Z axis to separate sides of an object. Then plug it as factor to control textures visibility.

Why Z, because in my case it is facing texures (see gizmo in Local mode).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I opened the file you linked, but the letters "A' and "B" dont appear the same as they are in your photo above. Instead, they are stretches out along the outer ring of the circle.

Comment: It is strange. What version of 2.8 do you have? Mine is 2.82 build.